# Необходима помощь с пониманием MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin

Пишу свое приложение по паттерну MVVM. В качества примера беру различные статьи.
Хочу написать с использованием ViewModel, Repository, Room, Coroutines.
Например имеется следующий код автора статьи:

```
@Database(entities = [MovieEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class MovieDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun movieDao(): MovieDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MovieDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): MovieDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }

            synchronized(MovieDatabase::class) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MovieDatabase::class.java,
                    "movie_database"
                )
                .build()

                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Обычный класс Database, с "вроде" паттерном "Singleton"
Далее Repository:

```
class MovieRepository(private val movieDao: MovieDao) {
    val allMovies: LiveData<List<MovieEntity>> = movieDao.getAll()

    suspend fun insert(movie: MovieEntity) {
        movieDao.insert(movie)
    }
}
```

И вот тут у меня возникают вопросы:

**Вопрос 1**: для чего передавать MovieDao в  конструкторе? По сути этот код показывает что для каждой Entity, нам необходим отдельный Repository (передается конкретный Dao, отвечающий за CRUD определенной Entity).

Разве это правильно? Я думал, что в проекте Repository должен быть 1, который и будет оберткой, над database и remote service.

Отсюда идет сразу 2 вопрос:

**Вопрос 2**: Почему Для Repository не сделать Singleton, так же как с Database, если он должен быть один.

Посмотрим дальше

```
class MovieViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: MovieRepository
    val allMovies: LiveData<List<MovieEntity>>

    init {
        val movieDao = MovieDatabase.getInstance(application).movieDao()
        repository = MovieRepository(movieDao)
        allMovies = repository.allMovies
    }

    fun insert(movie: MovieEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(movie)
    }
}
```

Тут автор использует в конструкторе Application, и наследует AndroidViewModel куда и передает applcation.
Также получает Repository(куда передает movieDao, который получил из Database).

Не легче было бы сделать так?
Создать класс Application, через который можно уже получать database, и repository

```
public class AppDelegate : Application(){
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    public fun getDatabase(): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
    }

    public fun getRepository() : DataRepository{
        return DataRepository.getInstance()
    }
}
```

Так как Application нам не нужен в ViewModel, то уберем его из конструктора и заменим AndroidViewModel на простой ViewModel.

Что думаете поэтому поводу?
И если не согласны с этим кодом, поскидывайте ссылки на статьи, git-репозитории, в которых используются только ViewModel, Repository, Room и Coroutine (androidx.room:room-coroutines), без всяких Dependency Injection (так как на данном этапе я не понимаю для чего они нужны)

Comment: Собственно, DI решает часть проблем, по которым у вас вопросы. Например он может заниматься созданием где нужно каких нужно синглтонов нужных сущностей и сетит их в нужные места нужным способом. Причём делает это просто (с точки зрения программиста, т.к. работает через кодогенерацию по аннотациям). Что же до репозитория, то, вроде, есть споры по поводу того как его использовать и за что он должен отвечать. Например, можно рассматривать его как абстракцию, позволяющую, при желании, заменить Room на что-то другое, не переписывая классы, где репозиторий используется.

Comment: Что же до того, должен быть один репозиторий на все таблицы в БД, то также можно по разному. Однако отдельные репозитории могут быть удобны в смысле разграничения доступа к сущностям в разных частях приложения. Например использование общего репозитория, позволит на экране просмотра фильмов стереть из БД юзеров, а отдельные репозитории для фильмов и юзеров не позволят это сделать

Comment: @ЮрийСпб просто когда все в кучи, трудно разбираться. Не подскажите ссылку на репозитории, где находятся все вышеописанные структуры + (так уж и быть с dependency injection, но как вроде их несколько, Dagger 2, Toothick, и вроде на Kotlin Koin или как его там)

Comment: Тут подсказать не смогу, т.к. с LiveData и корутинами дел не имел. Могу лишь на других либах вот такой репозиторий посоветовать: https://gitlab.com/terrakok/gitlab-client

Comment: @ЮрийСпб вы писали, что если несколько репозиториев, то нельзя будет на экране просмотра фильмов стереть из БД юзеров. А разве просто получить ссылку на второй Repository во Fragment (ну или там ViewModel) и удалить через него?

Comment: Конечно, всегда можно всё. Либо рефлексией вызвать любой закрытый метод, либо исполнить нативный код или вообще на уровень ядра ОС перейти и там вручную оперативной памятью манипулировать. Я говорю об условной "защите от дурака". Если составить класс для работы с фильмами, передав ему в конструктор репозиторий только для фильмов, то удалять из него юзеров будет сложнее, чем если передать общий репозиторий, который может всё. Цель - минимизировать возможности классов, чтобы они максимально служили только одной цели.